# How to add different button action to the second annotation /pin in map view using swift2

Tags: ios, swift3, mkmapview, mkannotation

Can any one help me to add different button action to the second annotation /pin (annotation2), Now the button do the same work in the two annotation pins how to do different work to each other . I'am using Swift3 in my project and this is my code . thanks

This is my code.

```
  import UIKit
  import MapKit
  import CoreLocation

 class MyAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
      var uniqueId: Int!
 }

  class LocationViewController: UIViewController , MKMapViewDelegate , CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!{

    didSet{
        map.delegate = self
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var locationInfo: UITextView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let locations = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.314627, 44.303500)

    let location2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.312149, 44.3024567)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02)

    let span2 = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locations, span)

     let region2 = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location2, span2)


    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    map.setRegion(region2, animated: true)


    let annotation = MyAnnotation()
    //annotation.setCoordinate(location)
    annotation.coordinate = locations
    annotation.title = "Zaid Homes"
    annotation.subtitle = "Hay aljameaa"

    annotation.uniqueId = 1

    map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let annotation2 = MyAnnotation()
    //annotation.setCoordinate(location)
    annotation2.coordinate = location2
    annotation2.title = "Zaid "
    annotation2.subtitle = "aljameaa"

    annotation.uniqueId = 2

    map.addAnnotation(annotation2)

    //Showing the device location on the map
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true;

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "AnnotationView Id")
    if view == nil{
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "AnnotationView Id")
        view!.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        view!.annotation = annotation
    }

    view?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = nil
    view?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)


    return view
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if (control as? UIButton)?.buttonType ==   UIButtonType.detailDisclosure {
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: false)
        if let myAnnotation = view.annotation as? MyAnnotation {
            if (myAnnotation.uniqueId == 1) {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "info", sender: view)
            }
            else  {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "info2", sender: view)
            }
        }            
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to know on which annotation you tap is using creating custom annotation class and adding annotation of it. So create one annotation class `MyAnnotation` child class of `MKPointAnnotation` and maintain one uniqueId with your multiple annotation.

```
class MyAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var uniqueId: Int!
}
```

Now you need to add annotation of type `MyAnnotation` instead of `MKPointAnnotation`.

```
let annotation = MyAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = locations
annotation.title = "Zaid Homes"
annotation.subtitle = "Hay aljameaa"
//Set uniqueId for annotation
annotation.uniqueId = 1    
map.addAnnotation(annotation)

let annotation2 = MyAnnotation()
annotation2.coordinate = location2
annotation2.title = "Zaid "
annotation2.subtitle = "aljameaa"
//Set uniqueId for annotation
annotation2.uniqueId = 2    
map.addAnnotation(annotation2)
```

Now check this `uniqueId` in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method on which annotation you tapped.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view:  MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if (control as? UIButton)?.buttonType ==   UIButtonType.detailDisclosure {
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: false)
        if let myAnnotation = view.annotation as? MyAnnotation {
            if (myAnnotation.uniqueId == 1) {
                 performSegue(withIdentifier: "info1", sender: view)
            }
            else  {
                 performSegue(withIdentifier: "info2", sender: view)
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help but I have error (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value) her  if (myAnnotation.uniqueId == 1)  when I press the button of annotation 2.

Comment: You forgot to set uniqueId to 1 and 2 check my answer when you are creating instance of `MyAnnotation` this line `annotation.uniqueId = 1`

Comment: No I do it , But still the same error . Can you clear more please .

Comment: @ZaidMustafa Edit your question with current code that you are trying.

Comment: Please check My question now . Thanks

Comment: @ZaidMustafa You forgot to set `uniqueId` for annotation 2 you are setting uniqueId 2 for the same `annotation` instead of `annotation2.uniqueId = 2`, Check that and set it and your problem solved

Comment: @ZaidMustafa Welcome make :) Glad it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by creating two subClass of MKPointAnnotation and then in the delegate's method you can do this :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view:  MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

if view is subClass1 {
    // do action for subclass 1

}
else if view is subClass2 {
   // do action for subClass 2
}
}
```

Please let me know if this resolve your problem.

**Update**

you can make the implementation of you delegate more simpler like this exemple :

```js
class ClassA:MKPointAnnotation{
    func doActionWhenCalloutTapped(){
        //do some action
    }
}

class ClassB:ClassA{
    override func doActionWhenCalloutTapped(){
        //do some actions for annotation of type B
    }
}

class ClassC:ClassA{
    override func doActionWhenCalloutTapped(){
        //do some actions for annotation of type C
    }
}

func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let annotation = ClassB()
    //annotation.setCoordinate(location)
    annotation.coordinate = locations
    annotation.title = "Zaid Homes"
    annotation.subtitle = "Hay aljameaa"
    
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    
    let annotation2 = ClassC
    //annotation.setCoordinate(location)
    annotation2.coordinate = location2
    annotation2.title = "Zaid "
    annotation2.subtitle = "aljameaa"
    
    map.addAnnotation(annotation2)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view:  MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    
    (view.annotation as! ClassA).doActionWhenCalloutTapped()
   
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the contain of these two subclasses.

Comment: thaï could be just empty (no extra feature) for this exemple. but this allows you (may be in the futur) to have some new features with different behaviours.